# Help on adjusting histogram plot created by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab

I am trying to create a tikzpicture similar to what I have made in MATLAB. MATLAB gives me the following result after running histogram:

```
myhistnorm = [ 0.1231   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0001  0.0001  0.0004  0.001   0.0048  0.0313  0.1562  0.3464  0.2684  0.0645  0.0036  0 ]
```

I have used the following bin:

```
mybin = [ 1e-15 1e-14 1e-13 1e-12 1e-11 1e-10 1e-9 1e-8 1e-7 1e-6 1e-5 1e-4 1e-3 1e-2 1e-1 1e+0 1e+1 1e+2 1e+3 ]
```

The image of the figure, which is created in MATLAB, can be found in this [link]: (http://www.flickr.com/photos/68902462@N08/8361739859/in/photostream).

[image]

Although I created a normalized histogram using TikZ, it differs from the non-normalized figure that MATLAB has created in some other aspects.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    axis on top,
    scale only axis,
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    ybar interval,
    x tick label as interval=false,
    xlabel = {$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot{\bf u}_{int}$},
    xtick={},
    xtickten={-16,-14,-12,...,4},
    yticklabel={},
    xmin=1e-16, xmax=1e+4,
    ymax=1,
    grid=none,
    ymajorgrids,
]
\addplot [fill=gray!50] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Upper Count
9.9e-15 1e-14    0.1231
1e-14 1e-13      0.0000
1e-13 1e-12      0.0000
1e-12 1e-11      0.0000
1e-11 1e-10      0.0000
1e-10 1e-9       0.0000
1e-9  1e-8       0.0000
1e-8  1e-7       0.0001
1e-7  1e-6       0.0001
1e-6  1e-5       0.0004
1e-5  1e-4       0.0010
1e-4  1e-3       0.0048
1e-3  1e-2       0.0313
1e-2  1e-1       0.1562
1e-1  1e+0       0.3464
1e+0  1e+1       0.2684
1e+1  1e+2       0.0645
1e+2  1e+3       0.0036
1e+3  1e+10      0.0000
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will create a figure like the one in this [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68902462@N08/8365562892/in/photostream)

[image]

1. One of the things that is different between the MATLAB figure and tikzpicture is that in MATLAB the numbers I provided in the array 'mybin' represent the **bin centers** and the **bin edges** adjust themselves with that. For example, for bin 1e-1, the bin edges are 0.055 and 0.55. Is there any way to implement this in tikzpicture automatically or I have to modify the TikZ histogram by myself?
2. Another thing, is the **range**. The outmost left and right bins are not displayed correctly. The bar should be ranged from **0 to 1e-14** but it is displayed differently. Also, it seems xtickten={-14,-12,...,4}, does not have any effect on the lower range of x-axis. How can I fix this? I want to show that from 0 to 1e-14 there are 0.1231 counts.
3. Why only 7 bars are displayed in the figure? **Some of the bins are missing**.
4. How can I change **the range of y-axis** so that 1e+0 is also displayed. I get error when I add ymax=1e+0 to the code. (Fortunately, in tikzpicture y-axis of the histogram can be in log mode and at the same time have the bars in the plot; this is what I desire.)

Could someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you heard of [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz)?

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to include the image of the compile tikzpicture you created...

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain how you generated the histogram data from your original data, and how you generated the PGFPlots code (it looks like you might already be using `matlab2tikz`)?

Comment: At first, I had used matlab2tikz but the problem is I wanted the y-axis to be in logarithmic mode, which MATLAB does not yield a nice result. Then I wrote my own code for that without using matlab2tikz.

Comment: @Ahmad: I'm still a bit confused: **1.** There seem to be some typos in your data table (e.g. `0.4130` vs. `0.0413`). **2.** So you want to supply the bin centres, but the leftmost bin should stretch from 0 to 1e-6, correct? Or from 0 to 0.5e-5, as your first question suggests? In any case, you won't end up with a *normalised* histogram: For a normalised histogram, the sum of the products of the bin widths and the bin values should add up to 1. In your case, they only add up to about 0.093. Could you edit your question to provide more detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jake, I have modified the question. Could you please upload both of the images? My main concern is why I cannot correct the ranges. I mean x-range (from 0 to 1e-14 and 1e+3 to infinity) and y-range (to also display 1e0). I am not very worried about the bin centers.

Comment: Could you please upload the first image too? I have modified it as well.

Comment: About question 2: Since you have a logarithmic x axis, you can't have a bar that goes from 0 to 1e-14. 0 can never be included in a logarithmic axis. Could you maybe draw a mockup of what you would like your plot to look like? By the way, `xtickten` does not influence the axis limits, but only the axis labels. To influence the limits, use `xmin=1e-14`. That also answers your fourth question: Set `ymax=1`.

Comment: Thanks Jake for your explanations. As for the mockup, I want to have a figure like the first figure in my question, which is created by MATLAB (but normalized).

Comment: I have modified the code in the question and have applied what I learned from the comments of this question. I am approaching to the figure I need. The problem is only the bins between 1e-14 to 1e-8. Could someone tell me why TikZ displays the bin different than what I have entered in the table? Could someone also update the second link (second image) in the question?

Comment: One other thing, do you think I'd better clean up this question and post a new one?

Comment: The second figure is updated in the link http://www.flickr.com/photos/68902462@N08/8365562892/in/photostream.

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes, I think it's a good idea to clean up this question. Generally, it's preferred to have only one question per post, because that makes it easier for others with similar problems to find the post. Also, you should try to come up with a more descriptive title. And finally, you can include images in your post yourself by clicking the "image" button in the editor.

Comment: Thanks. I have cleaned up the question in a new post which can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/tikz-bins-in-the-histogram-are-not-displayed-correctly